# Symfony manytomany with additonal table

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, many-to-many

I have a problem with understand how to join columns or tables in doctrine to get something like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lx1Fg.png)

What I want is to allow user add some prod_lines in form, next add some buttons in another form and then match prod_lines with buttons which user wants.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542243/doctrine2-best-way-to-handle-many-to-many-with-extra-columns-in-reference-table?rq=1

Comment: It's not so hard. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46819849/4548751) answer, and adapt one of the many-to-many relation from there to your case.